# piped sed does not output to file using ngrep

Tags: linux, bash, sed, ngrep

I am using ngrep to filter some tcp packetes into STDOUT
Since it now become more important to log the output (after changing the result a bit using`sed`) into a file.

piping it with `sed` looks OK in stdout - But no content is written when writing to `dump.log`

Below is the command:

`grep -l -q -W none -i "^POST /somefile.php" tcp and port 80 | sed -e 's/^T/IP/g' >> dump.log`

Having the impression that either sed or ngrep blocks the process of pushing the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-U` to GNU sed to load minimal amounts of data from the input and flush the output buffers more often.